# Intent to open a chat with a specific user on snapchat app

Tags: android, android-intent, schema, snapchat

I'm trying to find if there is any app schema,

to open the Snapchat app (via Intent) with a specific userID that I want to chat with?

BTW, to find the userID:

[image]

Comment: i am also looking for same thing but did n't get any help , please anyone guide us?

Answer (score 14):

This the only thing that works for me. Unfortunately, it adds the extra step of making the user choose the browser or Snapchat app.

```
Intent nativeAppIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://snapchat.com/add/" + snapchatId));
startActivity(nativeAppIntent);
```

Oddly enough, the URL scheme `snapchat://add/" + snapchatId` works on iOS but not on Android (it opens the Android app, but does not pop up the user).

**EDIT**: Add `intent.setPackage("com.snapchat.android");` and it will open the app without the chooser. But adding this means you will need to surround everything with a try/catch to prevent a crash.

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://snapchat.com/add/" + snapchatId));
    intent.setPackage("com.snapchat.android");
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://snapchat.com/add/" + snapchatId)));
}
```

Comment: On Android we can open with "snapchat://app/add", but it can't open profile