# Sending an intent to Snapchat

Tags: android, android-intent

```
 public void postStory (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        startActivity(intent);
```

So thats my Java code I took from another app i made to send an intent to the user's email. I'm pretty sure the package name for snapchat is

```
com.snapchat.android
```

I'm not sure how to send an intent to a social app. Any help is appreciated.

I would like the intent to open the user's snapchat to the main layout where you take a picture.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly you want ? You want to open Snachat app or Mail App?

Comment: what do you want to share exactly in snapchat app ? or need all the social app installed ?

Comment: I would like to open snapchat if they have it installed, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: you want to directly open snapchat capture screen correct ?

Comment: Yes ragu like where they take the picture at. I want them to take a picture but that picture doesn't have to apply to my app. I just want them to take a picture

Comment: so you don't want other apps to be listed. It should directly opens the snapchat app. correct?

Comment: Correct it is only for snapchat and if they don't have it I would like to direct them to the market place with a toast that explains why they're being redirected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103985/discussion-between-ragu-swaminathan-and-timmyspan).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch an application from another application on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android)

Comment: thanks for the help @cricket_007 ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this, it will open the Snapchat App directly if installed, other wise an msg showing no apps can perform this action.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.setPackage("com.snapchat.android");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open Snapchat"));
```

Best Wishes..!!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and code! When i tested this out it is still telling me ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN. I'm not sure why it isn't executing... wait i might have fixed it

Comment: Ragu you are great!! I forgot my onClick attribute in my XML... duhh lol! Thanks again :)

Comment: Hope you will be calling the above lines under some on click listener, correct ?

Comment: I wish there was a way to open a specific user, but it seems that it isn't really possible at this point. I haven't been able to figure it out at least and there is an empty question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436060/intent-to-open-a-chat-with-a-specific-user-on-snapchat-app).

Comment: i'm not sure at this point. Let me help you in this. give me some time.

Comment: Is there any way to share a video with intent?

Comment: Is there a way to request Snapchat to have a recording video session, where the user can record with their effects, and get it back to our app?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I'm not sure on this. Just give try to snapkit SDK https://docs.snapchat.com/docs/api/android/