# Sending an Intent to Snapchat?

Tags: android, android-intent, snapchat

I would like to open a specific user ID:

- Snapchat App (if available on mobile)
- or, Snapchat web site

I've developed this static method:

```
    public static Intent newSnapchatIntent(String id) {
        if (isApplicationEnabled(Defines.SNAPCHAT_PACKAGE_NAME)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.setPackage("com.snapchat.android");
            return intent;
        }
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(NetworkUtils.formatUrlPath("https://snapchat.com", id)));
    }
```

But I don't know how to open a specific user profil based on this #id. Have you got an idea guys?

Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/31436060/3505534

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to do that. But maybe this helps. There are GitHub repositories linked at the bottom if you need more.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/snapchat